# How to create redar diagram in excel using Epplus in dotnet 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have created report in excel sheet which Is described in image1 and this image should give redar diagram which in in Image2 in different excel sheet like given in screenshot.
there are two excel sheet in one excel as you can see in screenshot so in chart sheet there should be redar diagram and sheet named sheet there is excel report valud as you can see in screenshot

[image]

[image]

I have already done piechart and excel report as well and I get stocked while making redar diagram ,
example of that I had made piechart and excel report :

```
public static class TestRunTestCaseExportHelper {
    public static byte[] TestRunTestCaseByTestRunIdToExcel(List<TestRunTestCaseExportModel> data1, List<TestRunTestCaseExportTestResultCountModel> datas, List<FunctionModuleModel> funcitonData, TestRunTestCaseCountPercentageModel testRunStatusCountPercentage)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] result;
            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
            using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                int cellNumb = 1;
                string[] totalColumns = {
                            "SN",
                            "Test Case",
                            "Test Plan",
                            "Status"
                };

                string[] totalColumn = {
                            "Test Plan",
                            "Passed",
                            "Failed",
                            "Pending",
                            "Blocked",
                };

                string[] totalColumn3 = {
                            "Function",
                            "Count"
                };
                string[] totalColumn4 = {
                            "Status",
                            "Percentage",
                          
                };

              
                var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Chart");
                var worksheets = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("sheet");


                //worksheet.InsertRow(5, 2);
                var rand = new Random();
                var testRunStatusCountPercentages = testRunStatusCountPercentage;

                var data = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>
                        {
                            new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Passed", testRunStatusCountPercentages.PassedPercentage),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Failed", testRunStatusCountPercentages.FailedPercentage),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Pending",85),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Blocked", 15),

                        };
                for (var i = 0; i < totalColumn4.Length; i++)
                {
                    worksheets.Cells[1, i + 16].Value = totalColumn4[i]; //populate header row
                }
                var m = 2;
                //Fill the table
                var startCell = worksheets.Cells[1, 16];
               
              
                if (testRunStatusCountPercentage != null)
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        startCell.Offset(i  + 1, 0).Value = data[i].Key;
                        startCell.Offset(i  + 1, 1).Value = data[i].Value;
                    }

                    using (ExcelRange Rng = worksheets.Cells[1, 16, 5, data.Count + 13])
                    {
                        Rng.Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                        Rng.Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                        Rng.Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                        Rng.Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                    }
                }

                //Add the chart to the sheet
                var pieChart = worksheet.Drawings.AddChart("Chart1", eChartType.Pie);
                pieChart.SetPosition(data.Count + 1, 0, 0, 0);
                pieChart.Title.Text = "Test Case Excution Status";
                pieChart.Title.Font.Bold = true;
                pieChart.Title.Font.Size = 12;

                //Set the data range
                var series = pieChart.Series.Add(worksheets.Cells[2, 17, data.Count + 1, 17], worksheets.Cells[2, 16, data.Count + 1, 16]);
                var pieSeries = (ExcelPieChartSerie)series;
                pieSeries.Explosion = 5;

                //Format the labels
                pieSeries.DataLabel.Font.Bold = true;
                pieSeries.DataLabel.ShowValue = true;
                pieSeries.DataLabel.ShowPercent = true;
                pieSeries.DataLabel.ShowLeaderLines = true;
                pieSeries.DataLabel.Separator = ";";
                pieSeries.DataLabel.Position = eLabelPosition.BestFit;

                //Format the legend
                pieChart.Legend.Add();
                pieChart.Legend.Border.Width = 0;
                pieChart.Legend.Font.Size = 12;
                pieChart.Legend.Font.Bold = true;
                pieChart.Legend.Position = eLegendPosition.Right;


                // add a new worksheet to the empty workbook
               
                using (var cells = worksheets.Cells[1, 1, 1, totalColumns.Length]) //(1,1) => (1,10)
                {
                    cells.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                }
                using (var cells = worksheets.Cells[1, 7, 1, totalColumn.Length + 7]) //(1,1) => (1,10)
                {
                    cells.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                }

                using (var cells = worksheets.Cells[1, 13, 1, totalColumn3.Length + 13]) //(1,1) => (1,10)
                {
                    cells.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                } 
                using (var cells = worksheets.Cells[1, 16, 1, totalColumn4.Length + 16]) //(1,1) => (1,10)
                {
                    cells.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                }

                var records = data1.ToList();
                var list = datas.ToList();
                var funValue = funcitonData.ToList();
                int totalRows = data1.Count + 1; //data including header row
                int totalRowsList = datas.Count + 2;
                
                var totalRowsForFuntion = funcitonData.Count + 1;

                for (var i = 0; i < totalColumns.Length; i++)
                {
                    worksheets.Cells[1, i + 1].Value = totalColumns[i]; //populate header row
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < totalColumn.Length; i++)
                {
                    worksheets.Cells[1, i + 7].Value = totalColumn[i]; //populate header row
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < totalColumn3.Length; i++)
                {
                    worksheets.Cells[1, i + 13].Value = totalColumn3[i]; //populate header row
                } 
               

                //Add values
                var j = 2; //to start data from second row after the header row.
                var k = 2;
                var l = 2;
                if (data1 != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in records)
                    {

                        worksheets.Cells["A" + j].Value = cellNumb;
                        worksheets.Cells["B" + j].Value = item.TestCaseName;
                        worksheets.Cells["C" + j].Value = item.TestPlanName;
                        worksheets.Cells["D" + j].Value = item.Status;

                        j++;
                        cellNumb++;
                    }
                    using (ExcelRange Rng = worksheets.Cells[1, 1, totalRows, totalColumns.Length])
                    {
                        Rng.Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                        Rng.Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                        Rng.Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                        Rng.Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                    }

                }
                if (datas != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in datas)
                    {
                        worksheets.Cells["G" + k].Value = item.TestPlanNameForCount;
                        worksheets.Cells["H" + k].Value = item.TotalPassedCount;
                        worksheets.Cells["I" + k].Value = item.TotalFailedCount;
                        worksheets.Cells["J" + k].Value = item.TotalPendingCount;
                        worksheets.Cells["K" + k].Value = item.TotalBlockCount;
                        k++;

                    }
                    worksheets.Cells["G" + k].Value = "Total";
                    worksheets.Cells["H" + k].Value = datas.Sum(x => x.TotalPassedCount);
                    worksheets.Cells["I" + k].Value = datas.Sum(x => x.TotalFailedCount);
                    worksheets.Cells["J" + k].Value = datas.Sum(x => x.TotalPendingCount);
                    worksheets.Cells["K" + k].Value = datas.Sum(x => x.TotalBlockCount);

                    using (ExcelRange Rng = worksheets.Cells[1, 7, totalRowsList, totalColumn.Length + 6])
                    {
                        Rng.Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                        Rng.Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                        Rng.Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                        Rng.Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                    }
                }

                if (funcitonData != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in funValue)
                    {
                        worksheets.Cells["M" + l].Value = item.FunctionName;
                        worksheets.Cells["N" + l].Value = item.TotalCountTestCaseByTestRunId;

                        l++;

                    }


                    using (ExcelRange Rng = worksheets.Cells[1, 13, totalRowsForFuntion, totalColumn3.Length + 12])
                    {
                        Rng.Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                        Rng.Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                        Rng.Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                        Rng.Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                    }
                }
               
               


                worksheets.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
                result = package.GetAsByteArray();
                return result;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Download failed : {ex.Message}");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can [edit] your post, no need to explain in comments. But please add some more information, like the relationship between Excel and asp.Net

Comment: @HansKeﬆing sir plz help me to solve this problem.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing sir below is my own sir plz give feedback

Comment: Sorry, I don't use this Excel component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var redarChart = worksheet.Drawings.AddRadarChart("RadarChart", 
eRadarChartType.RadarMarkers);
redarChart.SetPosition(42, 0, 0, 0);
redarChart.SetSize(700, 300);
redarChart.Title.Text = "Function Map";
redarChart.Title.Font.Bold = true;
redarChart.Title.Font.Size = 12;

var serie = redarChart.Series.Add(worksheets.Cells[2, 14, funValue.Count + 1, 14], worksheets.Cells[2, 13, funValue.Count + 1, 13]);
serie.HeaderAddress = new ExcelAddress("'sheet'!N1");
redarChart.StyleManager.SetChartStyle(ePresetChartStyleMultiSeries.RadarChartStyle4);
redarChart.Fill.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
redarChart.Legend.Position = eLegendPosition.TopRight;
//If you want to apply custom styling do that after setting the chart style so its not overwritten.
redarChart.Legend.Effect.SetPresetShadow(ePresetExcelShadowType.OuterTopLeft);
var radarSeries = (ExcelRadarChartSerie)serie;
radarSeries.Marker.Size = 5;
```

Comment: I have done myself this will help you to create radar diagram using epplus in dotnet core